# Composer - private repo within private repo

Tags: git, composer-php

I am having issues with a private repository referenced inside another private repository.

See my core package here:

```
{
"name": "symfony/skeleton",
"type": "project",
"license": "MIT",
"description": "A minimal Symfony project recommended to create bare bones applications",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/console": "^4.1",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.1",
    "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.1",
    "tomcorbett/reeta-core": "dev-master",
    "wrep/daemonizable-command": "^2.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/dotenv": "^4.1",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.5",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true,
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "xxxxxxxx"
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@github.com:tomcorbett/omnivore-api.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@github.com:tomcorbett/reeta-core.git"
    }
],
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": true
    }
}
```

}

And inside the tomcorbett/reeta-core is this composer:

```
{
"name": "tomcorbett/reeta-core",
"description": "Main core library for sharing between API and web",
"type": "symfony-bundle",
"license": "proprietary",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^5.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.7",
    "google/cloud-pubsub": "^1.3",
    "msgphp/user-bundle": "^0.4.4",
    "ramsey/uuid-doctrine": "^1.4",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "simple-bus/symfony-bridge": "^5.1",
    "symfony/console": "^4.0",
    "symfony/expression-language": "^4.0",
    "symfony/form": "^4.0",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/process": "^4.0",
    "symfony/security": "^4.0",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/validator": "^4.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.0",
    "tomcorbett/omnivore-api": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true,
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "xxxxxxxxx"
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Reeta\\CoreBundle\\": "src/Reeta/CoreBundle"
    }
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@github.com:tomcorbett/omnivore-api.git"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false
    }
}
```

}

For some reason in my main package (the first composer.json), when I try to do:

```
composer require tomcorbett/reeta-core
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for tomcorbett/reeta-core dev-master -> satisfiable by tomcorbett/reeta-core[dev-master].
    - tomcorbett/reeta-core dev-master requires tomcorbett/omnivore-api dev-master -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
```

In case it's useful the composer.json of the tomcorbett/omnivore-api project is here:

```
{
"name": "tomcorbett/omnivore-api",
"type": "library",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Thomas Corbett",
        "email": "tom@tomctech.com"
    }
],
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Omnivore\\": "src/Omnivore"
    }
},
"require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.x"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.*"
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Omnivore\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

}

There is a similar question and a well written answer here [Composer won't load private repository within private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133269/composer-wont-load-private-repository-within-private-repository) but doesn't solve my problem just explains that it should work if anything.

From inside my main project when I do:

```
composer search tomcorbett/omnivore-api
```

I do indeed get

```
tomcorbett/omnivore-api
```

So this proves composer is aware of it so I am not sure why it is telling me the package is not found. And there definitely is a dev-master.

Also when I run composer install in my reeta-core project it installs the omnivore-api package just fine.

I do not want to have to use a private packagist or satis or anything as I believe what I want to do should work, just hopefully I am doing something stupid! This is driving me insane!

Thank you in advance!